# scp all files ending '-123.jpg' - recursion, spaces, wildcards …

Tags: ssh, terminal, scp

There's too much going on for me to get my noobie head around here. I'm wanting to download all files that end -123.jpg from a multitude of nested directories on a remote server. Some of these directories have spaces in their names. I'm thinking that the command should be along the lines of:

```
scp -r user@server:/path/to/parent\ directory/*/*/*123\.jpg ./
```

… where "parent\ directory" is a directory name with a space, and the specified path goes as deep as it can before it splits off to various sub-directories, for example dir/sub dir/[uniquely_id]-123.jpg file. (Note that these sub-directories often contain spaces too, should that affect the * wildcard)

I'm getting 'no match' returned for this, or 'no such file or directory' if I meddle with the space escaping. I'm thinking therefore that it's the recursion or the wildcard that I've got wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking your server layout for testing I don't know if the following command actually works, but I think rsync would be better than scp in that case, as you can specify in- and exclude patterns. Something like:

```
rsync -arvzSH  --include "*123.jpg" --exclude "*" user@server:/path/to/parent\ directory/ /path/to/target directory/
```

may work. But you better double check the [rsync documentation](http://www.samba.org/rsync/documentation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Filename escaping with scp is tricky; your arguments get (re)expanded on the remote side.  "Interesting" characters have to be double quoted, to avoid special handing by your local shell and by the remote.  I would expect both the following to work for you:

```
scp user@server:'/path/to/parent\ directory/*/*/*123.jpg' ./
scp user@server:'"/path/to/parent directory"/*/*/*123.jpg' ./
```

If that's confusing, rsync is pretty easy to use (as lothar mentions), and piping tar or cpio through ssh is pretty easy too.

```
ssh user@server 'cd /path/to/parent\ directory;
                 find -name "*123.jpg" -print0 | cpio -0 -o' |
    cpio -i -d -v
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around for scp with wildcards:

```
for i in "*-123.jpg"
do 
    scp $i <user>@<server>:/path/to/destination/
done
```

Refer: https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/How-to-scp-mutiple-files-using-wild-chars-or-in-a-single-scp/m-p/3639440/highlight/true#M238959

Comment: What if filename of the file will contain space? It won't work, I think. Maybe `find` command would be better (with xargs)?

Comment: Not sure why -1 ? the solution works. If there are other scenarios it can be improved further. But the given solution is NOT wrong.

Comment: For this particular question the answer is ok, but we try to make things universal. There are few bugs in this answer: 1. never `for` `ls` 2. `$i` should be in quotes 3. `find` should be used

Comment: 1) updated the answer to remove 'ls', not required. 
2) $i works without quotes
3) works for files with space in names.

Comment: I'm not sure what shell you're using, but in de-facto standard sh/bash, an unquoted $i will have its value subject to word-splitting and so values with spaces in them will not work as expected – they'll be passed to _scp_ as multiple arguments, each having part of the file name.

Comment: I am running bash shell. When I put single quote around $i , then error:
$i: No such file or directory

If I put double quote then I get error:
*-123.jpg: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

This properly should be done in two parts:

1. first find all needed files and copy them to one folder (this does not work if you have the same filenames) - you may do it with one `find` and `-exec`
2. then send a bunch of files using `scp`

`scp` is not enough advanced to copy folders structure and there is no single command to make a copy of a folders tree.

Also, if you need all files in folders, as you will not be able to select them by wildcards, and you want to preserve folders structure - you may want to use `mc` = Midnight Commander and its "Shell link".